# Qt - program works when started inside qtcreator, but segfaults if started from the console

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have a strange problem, when i start my Qt program with Qtcreator or in the folder that Qtcreator created (projectname-build-desktop) , it works, but if i want to compile the code with qmake and make, i get Segmentation fault on launch. 
Gdb tells me that :

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0089bc37 in QTableView::verticalHeader() const () from /usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4

the problem comes from a function filling a QtableWidget. How is it possible that it works in one case and not the other ? 
Here is the function :

```
void Xml::ajout_ligne_nouveaute (Ui::MainWindow * ui, QString type, QString nom,QString artiste)
{
          is_there_new = true;

          ui->table_new->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
          ui->table_new->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);

            // makes the cells more little
            QHeaderView *verticalHeader = ui->table_music->verticalHeader();
            verticalHeader->setDefaultSectionSize(verticalHeader->fontMetrics().height()+3);


            ui->table_new->setShowGrid(false);


            // auto dimention
            QHeaderView *headers = ui->table_new->horizontalHeader();
            headers->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);


            // column number
            ui->table_new->setColumnCount(3);

             // column name
             QStringList header;
             header << "Type" << "Name" << "Artist" ;
             ui->table_new->setHorizontalHeaderLabels ( header );

             // remove left header
             ui->table_new->verticalHeader()->hide();


             // number of current columns
             ui->table_new->setRowCount(offset_courant_nouveaute);


             // one item by cell
             QTableWidgetItem * name  = new QTableWidgetItem(nom, 1000);

             QTableWidgetItem * artist  = new QTableWidgetItem(artiste, 1000);

             QTableWidgetItem * typ  = new QTableWidgetItem(type, 1000);

             ui->table_new->setItem(offset_courant_nouveaute-1, 0, name);
             ui->table_new->setItem(offset_courant_nouveaute-1, 1, artist);
             ui->table_new->setItem(offset_courant_nouveaute-1, 2, typ);


             if(offset_courant_nouveaute%2)
             {
                 QColor * couleur = new QColor( 227, 248, 255, 255);

                 typ->setBackgroundColor(*couleur);
                 artist->setBackgroundColor(*couleur);
                 name->setBackgroundColor(*couleur);
             }

   offset_courant_nouveaute ++;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check LD_LIBRARY_PATH and if needed set it to point QTSDK lib.

Comment: I don't think it's a library problem, i'm using the same functions in other parts of the code, and they work. I removed the "shadow build" from qtcreator, so now it starts from the same folder, and it crashes.

Comment: Dump of assembler code for function _ZNK10QTableView14verticalHeaderEv:
0x0089bc30  <+0>:             push   %ebp
0x0089bc31  <+1>:             mov    %esp,%ebp
0x0089bc33  <+3>:             mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x0089bc36  <+6>:             pop    %ebp
0x0089bc37  <+7>:             mov    0x4(%eax),%eax
0x0089bc3a  <+10>:             mov    0x2ac(%eax),%eax
0x0089bc40  <+16>:             ret
        End of assembler dump.

Comment: If you are sure that it is not related to lib version maybe try to split that code to parts and do something similar to assert(part1 != NULL)